# Javascript array : why is this not valid?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following working code :

```
var routes = [];
```

Eclipse validator for javascript prints the following warning :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to any
```

What is wrong with my empty array ?

**Edit** : the warning disappeared later. Apparently Eclipse was wrong and the question needs to be closed. Sorry about that.

Comment: You sure it's happening at that line?

Comment: Eclipse says that, but what does the browser say?

Comment: My eclipse doesn't say anything when I try this.

Comment: Neither does http://jslint.com, which makes me think it's okay

Comment: show more code. There's probably an error before it that makes it confused on that line. Also, are you sure you're using the JavaScript validator and *not* the Java validator?

Comment: :( nevermind after editing/saving the file 5-10 times, the warning disappeared... Sorry about that :p, but yeah that was really at that line, nothing above, another declaration like that under. Don't know what happened, we can close the question.

Comment: My answer below explains in what situation this would occur. This is tricky and not everyone will experience it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your JavaScript is valid, the problem is with JSDT plugin for Eclipse. In the latest version they introduced a type verification which is problematic in many situations - not only for empty arrays (like in your case). Another typical case may look like this: `a = b || c;`
The plugin will complain when b and c are of different types (which is absolutely valid code for JavaScript). There is several bugs  already reported to JSDT developers about this problem, but the issues are not fixed yet.

Unfortunately currently it is not possible to switch off the type verification using JSDT configuration screen in Eclipse. I switched it off directly from the JSDT source code. To do this, please follow these steps:

1. Download the JSDT source code from [Eclipse WebTools Project](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/?root=WebTools_Project)
2. Open the `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.core` project with Eclipse. Make sure you have Eclipse SDK installed. It might also be required to adjust some dependencies in the `plugin.xml` file.
3. The type verification is located in `computeSeverity` method of `ProblemReporter` class.
4. To switch off type verification replace the line: `case IProblem.TypeMismatch: return ProblemSeverities.Warning;` with `case IProblem.TypeMismatch: return ProblemSeverities.Ignore;`
5. Build the project and close Eclipse.
6. In Eclipse folder find the file named `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core<version>.jar` - make a safe copy of it, then open the jar file and replace the `ProblemReporter.class` file with the one you compiled in the step 5 (the file is in `bin` folder of your project).
7. Start Eclipse and clean your JavaScript project. All type checking will be ignored by JSDT.

Important! Make sure you've downloaded the same version of JSDT that you are using in Eclipse. Eventually instead of replacing a single file you can replace the entire plugin.

If you don't want to download and compile the plugin by yourself you can try with my fixed version. I've placed it on my [FunctionSack](http://functionsack.com/eclipse/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core_1.1.100.v201104272153.jar) webpage. I am using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) with JSDT 1.3.0, so make sure you have similar configuration if you want to use my file.

Answer (score 11):

The eclipse's web tools platform plugin (wtp) includes a JavaScript validator that is somewhat allergic to the object literal "{}" and array literal "[]" notations, it also shows up some other annoying 'problems' such as 'missing semicolon' etc.

I have found the best solution for me and for my nerves is to disable the wtp's-embedded JavaScript validation completely and use a third-party plug-in.
Surprisingly it's not that easy to disable JavaScript validator. Every eclipse versions requires a different approach, so try the following guide:

- In Eclipse prior to version 3.6 it was possible to disable javascript
  validation via
  'Window->Preferences->JavaScript->Validator->Errors/Warnings->[ ]
  Enable JavaScript Semantic validation" - but this doesn't seem to
  work in 3.7 Indigo see the [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338759)
- In 3.7 Indigo try Project -> Properties -> Builders - > [ ] JavaScript Validator
- If doesn't help, try Project -> Properties -> JavaScript -> Include Path -> Source -> Excluded -> Edit -> Exclusion Patterns -> Edit -> **/*
- If nothing above helps, open .project file and delete/comment out "<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>" line

After disabling the wtp validator you can try using a third party tool such as [jsLint/jsHint](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/)

Answer (score 4):

As what I observed in my testing so far, the problem occurs when you define a local variable in a function which body following a `return` keyword. This scenario can be shown in the following example (assuming the code is in a top level JavaScript file, means not inside any module/function so the first `a` is defined in global scope):

```
var a=[]; //Global variable assignment, no warnings

function f1(){ //global function
    var a=[]; //level 1 local variable, no warnings
    return a;
}

function f2(){ //local functions and member functions
    var f = function(){
        var a=[]; // no warinings
        return a;
    };
    this.f = function(){
        var a=[]; //no warnings
        return a;
    };
    return f; //returning a defined funciton is OK
}

function f3(){ //returning a function
    return function(){
        var a=[]; //warning: Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to any
        return a;
    };
}
```

So the workaround is simple: change f3 to

```
function f3(){ //returning a defined function
    var f = function(){
        var a=[]; //warning is gone!
        return a;
    };
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's valid Javascript (assuming you're not writing it in some wierd context like the middle of an expression :P) so either the "Eclipse validator for javascript" is broken, or you're not using the "Eclipse validator for javascript" after all.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely valid JS and sounds like Eclipse may be using the incorrect syntax plugin or something is ... well ... wrong.

You can confirm this by trying...

```
var routes = [];
routes.push({ url: '/' });
console.log(routes.length);
```